# Add string before character in nested list using python

Tags: python, list, python-re

I have a long nested list of times. I want to add '0' before one-digit numbers of time in the list (like result list). I have tried the below code block, but it doesn't work. I know that using Regular expression is the best solution for the issue. But I don't have any experiences of `re` package. How can I solve the issue using `re` package or any other solution?

```
mylist = [
    ['x', '6:00 - 9:30 AM - 10:30 AM - 2:00 PM - 5:00 PM - 9:00 PM'],
    ['y',  '7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 1:30 PM']
]

result = [
    ['x', '06:00 - 09:30 AM - 10:30 AM - 02:00 PM - 05:00 PM - 09:00 PM'],
    ['y', '07:30 AM - 02:30 PM, 07:30 AM - 02:30 PM, 07:30 AM - 01:30 PM']
]


for idx, (id,name) in enumerate(list3):
    if  len(name.split('-')[0].split(':')[0]) <2 and  len(name.split('-')[1].split(':')[0]) <3:
         list3[idx][1] = '0'+name.split('-')[0] + ' - ' + '0'+ name.split('-')[1].strip()
         # print 1
    if len(name.split('-')[0].split(':')[0]) < 2 and len(name.split('-')[1].split(':')[0]) == 3:
        list3[idx][1] = '0' + name.split('-')[0] + ' - ' +  name.split('-')[1].strip()
    if len(name.split('-')[0].split(':')[0]) == 2 and len(name.split('-')[1].split(':')[0]) < 3:
        list3[idx][1] =  name.split('-')[0] + ' - ' + '0'+name.split('-')[1].strip()
```

Comment: "I know that using Regular expression is the best solution for the issue" I don't think it is. I think you should use the `datetime` module to parse the time values in the string, and then to format the time values in the desired output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, `(\d+?:)` would match `06:, 09:, 10: ..` then use [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) to prefix zero's

```
import re

mylist = [['x', '6:00 - 9:30 AM - 10:30 AM - 2:00 PM - 5:00 PM - 9:00 PM'],
          ['y', '7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 1:30 PM']]

print(
    [[re.sub("(\d+?:)", lambda m: m.group(1).rjust(3, '0'), y) for y in x]
     for x in mylist]
)
```

---

```
[['x', '06:00 - 09:30 AM - 10:30 AM - 02:00 PM - 05:00 PM - 09:00 PM'],
 ['y', '07:30 AM - 02:30 PM, 07:30 AM - 02:30 PM, 07:30 AM - 01:30 PM']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```py
import re

mylist = [['x', '6:00 - 9:30 AM - 10:30 AM - 2:00 PM - 5:00 PM - 9:00 PM'], ['y',  '7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 1:30 PM']] 

result = [['x', '06:00 - 09:30 AM - 10:30 AM - 02:00 PM - 05:00 PM - 09:00 PM'], ['y',  '07:30 AM - 02:30 PM, 07:30 AM - 02:30 PM, 07:30 AM - 01:30 PM']]


for idx, (id,name) in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[idx][1] = re.sub(r"(?<!\d)(\d:\d{2})", r"\1", mylist[idx][1])

# result:
[['x', '06:00 - 09:30 AM - 10:30 AM - 02:00 PM - 05:00 PM - 09:00 PM'], ['y', '07:30 AM - 02:30 PM, 07:30 AM - 02:30 PM, 07:30 AM - 01:30 PM']]
```

Comment: Would using a regex with a lookaround work better? I came up with `(?<=^|\D)(\d:\d{2})` which matches for any non-digit character or the string beginning without capturing it in the group.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that'd be more efficient :D its late where I am and I'm absolutely burnt: there's no reason to make a non-capturing group inside a capturing group.....

Comment: Hey @BBG_GIS , copied it wrong, used a result that wasn't my final answer

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
mylist = [['x', '6:00 - 9:30 AM - 10:30 AM - 2:00 PM - 5:00 PM - 9:00 PM'], ['y',  '7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 1:30 PM']] 
result = []

for x in mylist:
  res = x[0]
  s = []
  for y in x[1].split(' '):
    if len(y) == 4:
      t = '0' + y 
      s.append(t)
    else:
      s.append(y)
  s = ' '.join(s)
  result.append([res,s])

print(result)
```

Iterates through the given list (my list) , stores first element (x or y) then splits list of times and iterates through that list.  if the length of the current string is 4 then it needs a zero added to the beginning, adds zero and appends to new string,  otherwise add to new string s.  adds string to results. lmk if you have any questions I know the explanation could be a bit better but the code should be pretty easy to read.  This isn't the most efficient solution by any means and really only works if the time list string is relatively unchanging in format (so all times that need a zero will always be length of 4 and no other element in the split string will be length of 4).

Comment: Thanks for your soultion. I used your solution for another case.

Answer (score 0):

I have tailored a solution for one string, put it in a function and activate on each string:

```
import re
str = '7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 2:30 PM, 7:30 AM - 1:30 PM'
newStr = ""
isLead  = False
for char in str:
    if not isLead:
        if re.match("[0-9]", char ):
            isLead = True
            newStr += "0"
    if char == "M":
        isLead = False
    newStr += char

print(newStr)
```

If you really don't want to use regular expressions -

```
char.isnumeric()
```

Should work as well

Comment: I would recommend against using `str` as a variable name, and this also turns `10:30` to `010:30`. `char.isnumeric()` is a good touch.

Comment: That's right, you should combine with another solution offered here use (\d+?:) as your re

Comment: But then you can't use is numeric, tough edge case

Answer (score 0):

As it has been proposed in the comments, a proper way to solve your problem is to use time parsing tools, not regular expressions:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dateutil import parser

def fmt_time(t):
    return dt.strftime(parser.parse(t), "%I:%M %p")

result = [[item[0], 
           " - ".join(fmt_time(t) for t in item[1].split("-"))] 
          for item in mylist]
```